# It is possible to print a PDF file via LPR in Java?

Tags: java, lpr

I've been working in a LPR printing solution in Java. My point is if it is possible to print a PDF file with this protocol (with any combination of commands).

The working mode is opening a socket with the printer (port 515) and write some commands.